# Google Apps Scripting error returns unreliable information when using multiple libraries

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, try-catch

I'm trying to debug code and noticed that GAS will only report the stack from the top level function and the library it is calling.  If the library that is being called is calling a second library, none of the second library will be mentioned in the stack. My question is "is this expected or am I doing something wrong?" If it is expected, is there a best practices work around that I should be doing?

Notice that my logging indicates that I am calling 5 different functions but only 3 are indicated below in the error stack.

Update: After more work on this, I've noticed that the problem is that the error stack in Google Apps Script is unpredictable. Sometimes it will report the error stack in the initiating code and only the first library that it calls. Sometimes it will report only the the error stack coming from the 2nd library.

For comparison, the two functions are contained in the apps script editor link below. The only difference is whether or not I am passing the parameter 'sheet' to the functions I am calling.

https://script.google.com/home/projects/1HDi3uXD8cKJfl1jzfkopc9ZihCWBfRVukD_fIefUTtkD_mzLKS7DoGPo/edit

Here is the execution transcript and error stack from the first function...

```
10:26:49 AM Info Initiating Function with getRangeWithError... 
10:26:49 AM Info Running testError2 in Library1... 
10:26:49 AM Info Running testError3 in Library1... 
10:26:49 AM Info Running testError4 in Library2... 
10:26:49 AM Info Running testError5 in Library2... 
10:42:12 AM Error Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.
  testError3    @ Code.gs:8
  testError2    @ Code.gs:3
  getRangeWithErrorFromSpreadsheet  @ Code.gs:5
```

Here is the execution transcript and error stack from the 2nd function

```
10:18:41 PM Info    Initiating Function V2 with getRangeWithError...
10:18:41 PM Info    Running testError2 in Library1...
10:18:41 PM Info    Running testError3 in Library1...
10:18:41 PM Info    Running testError4 in Library2...
10:18:41 PM Info    Running testError5 in Library2...
10:48:02 AM Error   Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.
  testError5_v2 @ Code4.gs:23
  testError4_v2 @ Code4.gs:16
```

Here are the links to Library1 and Library2

Library1
https://script.google.com/home/projects/1TzR5ftIV822kwIOuynD6lPlQr9hr67zhEMO5z-0119dUV7nCsvcNcqnJ/edit

Library2
https://script.google.com/home/projects/1BaaMLhmMZZ8QEy6ZzjpzYcDTPRD8zzm6Lx727dzLxTwVZFKQktfTSp2s/edit